# ROS2 Mixing DDS / Middleware Between Nodes

Tags: ros2, dds

Looking to understand the limits of ROS2 right now so I can architect my system better. Is it possible to run different DDS implementations on different nodes (e.g. fast-dds and cyclone-dds) or will this cause issues with topics and services? My main reason for asking is the use-case where I am communicating with an existing system that is running a different DDS than the one I have configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on a robot which is running fastrtps while all stuff on my side is running cyclonedds. From my experience I can say that with default configs on the cyclone (not certain if the fastrtps is running with defaults...) topics seem to work quite ok. Services were something I was not able to make work properly (cyclone -> fastrtps).

A while back I had problems (and again having some, not sure yet what it is this time...). Last time my problems were somehow related to a cyclonedds config that I was setting. As soon as I removed the config the connection began to work again. In the configs we were mainly setting the [multicast to spdp](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/blob/master/docs/manual/options.md#cycloneddsdomaingeneralallowmulticast)

So it can work but it can be quite finicky. As disclaimer I would say that I am not a dds wizard. Maybe there is some configs which can be tweaked to make those work better together. This has been my experience on the topic so far.